# Hexcode generator in python

Tags: python, x86, bytecode

I am trying to generate a hexcode generator in python for an assigment in school.

I would like to bruteforce the address space, however, I am not able to construct real hexcodes in python.

my script:

```
 for j in range(0, 100):
       var = "\\x%x" % j
       newpath = "\xa0\xf4\xff"+var
       print newpath
```

The bytecodes "\xa0\xf4\xff" gets printed correctly - as proper hexcodes. However, my bruteforcer is not able to generate real hexcodes but only strings "\xab" etc. How do I generate real hexcodes: Essentially, I would like to generate the entire address space of a 32-bit machine.

EDIT:
More specifically, by looking at some arbitrary output you can see the last "hexcode" is not considered a hexcode, but rather a string:

```
 ���\x5d
 ���\x5e
 ���\x5f
 ���\x60
 ���\x61
 ���\x62
 ���\x63
```

Answer (score 0):

Hex is just a different representation of a number. It is using base 16 instead of base 10 which is what we are normally used to.

With that in mind, any number is can be represented as a hex number:

```
for i in range(0, 0x20):
    print "0x%08X" %i
```

the output is

```
0x00000000
0x00000001
0x00000002
0x00000003
...
0x0000000E
0x0000000F
0x00000010
0x00000011
...
```

By using `%X` in the print statement we say "interpret as base 16". You can also specify a number in its hex representation, as I did in the `range(0, 0x20)` statement.

The reason that you see the printout of `"\xa0\xf4\xff"` is because python cannot substitute the values in that string into characters and prints the next best thing, a string representation of the number. Do not confuse an array of four bytes with its 32 bit word representation or its four character string representation, *it's the same thing!*

I would recommend you to play around with the built in functions `ord()`, `hex()` and `chr()` to get a feeling for how things work. Example:

```
print ord('a')
print hex(10)
print chr(97)
```

output:

```
97
0xa
a
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to write a function to do get the output you want:

```
def hexrepr(s):
    quotechar = '"' if s.count("'") >= s.count('"') else "'"
    rep = [quotechar]
    for ch in s:
        # control char?
        if ch != quotechar:
            rep += '\\x{:02x}'.format(ord(ch))
        else: # escape embedded quotechar
            rep += "\\{}".format(ch)
    rep += quotechar
    return "".join(rep)

for j in xrange(100):
    newpath = "\xa0\xf4\xff" + chr(j)
    print hexrepr(newpath)
```

Output:

```
"\xa0\xf4\xff\x00"
"\xa0\xf4\xff\x01"
"\xa0\xf4\xff\x02"
"\xa0\xf4\xff\x03"
  ...
"\xa0\xf4\xff\x61"
"\xa0\xf4\xff\x62"
"\xa0\xf4\xff\x63"
```